# Noise level of convect back microwaves

Tags: oven

Are all convect bake microwave ovens noisey while using the oven for baking?  My current oven sounds like the microwave is engaged while baking.

Comment: There are indeed combination ovens which keep the microwave on while baking. I can't tell you if you can recognize it by the noise, but I think it is worth it for you to try finding out more about it.

Comment: Can you tell us what brand and model is it?

Answer (score 1):

A combination microwave/convection or microwave/infrared oven will have a special fan to cool the circuitry while the non-microwave heating is engaged. This can be quite loud.

Comment: The convection mode often uses a fan as well. These fans are considerably noisier than the actual microwave generation, but there's often a fan to cool the electronics that make the microwaves, and that may make the sound the OP associates with microwaving